# Move directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash, directory, size, cd

I need to use "cd" on a shell script: move to the directory $home/folder/sub-folder
and then check with a conditional statement if the directory's size is more than 2 MB.

How could I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of this task you have issue with? What have you tried already?

Comment: @kamituel The movement to other directory. I tried with alias, but my Terminal does not recognize it as a valid function or statement.

Comment: @soulblazer What do you mean `tried with alias`? Put any relevant code in question, as written it's completely unclear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @BroSlow `alias A = /home/Alicante/A`

The terminal as if it's a invalid statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *suggestion*, you should definitively take a look at [`man du`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html). Something like that might be a good starting point:

```
du -s $home/folder/sub-folder
```